# Filter expression condition for no filter (remove filter) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is how i'm setting the FilterExpr

```
$scope.ChangeFilter = function() {
    if ($routeParams.SCId)  {
        $scope.FilterExpr = {'SubCategoryID': $routeParams.SCId.toString()};
    }
   else {
        $scope.FilterExpr = //What should be here //
   }
};
```

Here I m using it

```
<div class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products  | filter:SearchText | filter:FilterExpr:true| orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <!-- Display filtered Products -->
</div>
```

If $routeParams.SCId is not present, i want to make it equivalent of:

```
<div class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products  | filter:SearchText | orderBy:'ProductName'">
    <!-- Display filtered Products -->
</div>
```

What should be the expression in else part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by `ng-if` may be there is a better way to do this,

**if there is `SCId` in the scope** then this will display and other one is remove from the dom.

```
<div ng-if="SCId" class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products  | filter:SearchText | filter:FilterExpr:true| orderBy:'ProductName'">
<!-- Display filtered Products -->
```

**if there is no `SCId` in the scope** then this will display and other one is remove from the dom.

```
<div ngif="!SCId" class='box' ng-repeat="product in ProductService.Products  | filter:SearchText | orderBy:'ProductName'">
<!-- Display filtered Products -->
```

and add scope variable using `$routeParams`,

in controller,

```
$scope.SCId = $routeParams.SCId;
```

Comment: I am fine with the suggestion, but thing is there is around 50 lines of code for displaying filtered products. So i think this will be code duplicate.  Can we avoid it any how?

Comment: do mean you have lots of codes inside `ng-repeat` div ? and do u need to avoid from duplicating ?

Comment: yes, because if i ll have both the <div>s you suggested, same code will be there inside both.

Comment: ok, then you can create a template based on the common piece of codes and include it into the repeat div here is a demo http://plnkr.co/edit/reV7JZ2TVefOmg5yFZse?p=preview